# Evaluating $\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin(x)) dx$ using the Beta, Gamma and Digamma Functions.

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

Evaluate

> $$I(\theta)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \ln(\sin(\theta))d\theta$$
> $$$$

My attempt:$$$$
Consider $$J(a,0)=\int_0^{\pi/2} \sin^a(\theta)cos^0(\theta) d\theta$$
$\dfrac{d}{da}J(0,0)=I(\theta)$$$$$
Now, $J(a,0)=\beta\bigg (\dfrac{a+1}{2},\dfrac{1}{2}\bigg ) = \dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{a+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{a+2}{2})}$
$$\Longrightarrow I(\theta)= \dfrac{d}{da}J(0,0) = \dfrac{\partial}{\partial a}\dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{a+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{a+2}{2})}\bigg |^{a=0}$$
$$$$
$$\dfrac{d}{da}J(0,0) = \dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\bigg (\Gamma(\frac{a+2}{2})\bigg )^2} \bigg (\frac{1}{2}\Gamma'(\frac{a+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{a+2}{2}) -\frac{1}{2}\Gamma ' (\frac{a+2}{2})\Gamma(\frac{a+2}{2})\bigg ) $$
$$$$
$$= \dfrac{\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{a+2}{2})} \bigg ( \frac{1}{2}\psi(\frac{a+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{a+2}{2})-\frac{1}{2}\psi(\frac{a+2}{2})\Gamma(\frac{a+1}{2})\bigg ) $$
$$$$
$$= \dfrac{\frac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{a+1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})}{\Gamma(\frac{a+2}{2})}\bigg (\psi(\frac{a+1}{2}) -\psi(\frac{a+2}{2})\bigg ) $$
$$$$
$$\Longrightarrow \dfrac{d}{da}J(0,0) = \dfrac{1}{2}\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\Gamma(\frac{1}{2})\bigg (\psi(\frac{1}{2}) -\psi(1)\bigg ) =I(\theta) $$

Comment: first of all you should clear up your notation. furthermore, what do you know a bout special values of the digamma function?

Comment: I solved the digamma evaluation using [Wolfram](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=digamma+%281%2F2%29+-digamma%281%29)

Comment: $I$ is not a function of $\Theta$, $\partial_a J(0,0)$ makes no sense...and some more things

Comment: Replace $I(\Theta)$ by $I$ because it is not a function of $\Theta$.
And write $\partial_a J(a)|_{a=0}$ instead of $\partial_aJ(0)$, because this is the derivative of a constant ant therefore 0.

Comment: Looks fine to me...

Comment: $\partial_b\left(\partial_aI(a,b)\right)|_{a=b=0}$

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does give the correct answer, indeed. I think you only need the powerful identity:
$$ \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(n+a)(n+b)}=\frac{\psi(a)-\psi(b)}{a-b}\tag{1}$$
that follows from the series definition of the digamma function. That gives, for instance:
$$\log 2 = \sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{(-1)^{n+1}}{n} = \sum_{n\geq 0}\frac{1}{(2n+1)(2n+2)} = \frac{1}{2}\left(\psi(1)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)\right).\tag{2}$$

Answer (score 0):

Noticing that $$
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin x) d x=I^{\prime}(0),
$$
where the parameterized integral $$
I(a)=\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \sin^a x d x=\frac{\sqrt{\pi}}{2} \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)}{\Gamma\left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)}
$$
Logarithmic differentiation gives
$$
\frac{I^{\prime}(a)}{I(a)}=\frac{1}{2}\left[\psi\left(\frac{a+1}{2}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{a+2}{2}\right)\right]
$$
Hence we may conclude that
$$
\begin{aligned}
I^{\prime}(0) & =\frac{\pi}{2} \cdot \frac{1}{2}\left[\psi\left(\frac{1}{2}\right)-\psi(1)\right] \\
& =\frac{\pi}{4}(-\ln 4) \\
\int_0^{\frac{\pi}{2}} \ln (\sin x) d x& =-\frac{\pi}{2} \ln 2
\end{aligned}
$$

Comment: First line, I think you might be forgetting the $x$ in $dx$.

Comment: Thank you very much.  Fixed.